# Model validation error and test error

Tags: regression, machine-learning, probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics

Does choosing a model with the lowest validation error also guarantee that the model has the lowest test error?

Comment: By "validation", do you mean part of the training data set aside to evaluate model predictions, and by "test" another separate dataset on which we evaluate the final model after multiple tune-fit-validate cycles on the training and validation sets? (I'm asking because there are two contradictory conventions about the terms "test" and "validation" dataset.)

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

First, there is always residual variance, so even if the model with the lowest validation error has the lowest *expected* prediction error, for any given dataset, it may still have a higher error than a competing model.

Second, there is such a thing as "overfitting to the validation set": if you fit and tweak your model, then assess it on the validation set, then go back and tweak some more, iterating the process, then you will end up with a model whose predictions closely follow the validation set - and you may overfit here. Essentially, once you go back to the modeling stage after looking at the validation set, it is not a validation set any more. And once you have overfitted to your validation set, your performance on a true holdout test set may of course be worse than for a non-overfitted model.